# getting whole ledger history in QLDB

Tags: sql, amazon-qldb, partiql

Is there any way to get a history of the whole ledger instead of getting history on table level in QLDB?

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to get the history using the PartiQL query interface, you can only get it at a table level using the [`history()` function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/working.history.html).

However, QLDB also lets you export the entire journal to an S3 bucket using the [Export Journal](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/export-journal.html) feature. You can also stream all data from your ledger to a Kinesis Data Stream using [QLDB Streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/streams.html). Both these methods stream all historical revisions of data in your ledger across all your tables.

Checkout the following samples for both features:

Export - https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-qldb-dmv-sample-java/blob/v1.x/src/main/java/software/amazon/qldb/tutorial/ExportJournal.java

Stream - https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-qldb-dmv-sample-java/blob/v1.x/src/main/java/software/amazon/qldb/tutorial/streams/StreamJournal.java